# Mid 2009 Macbook Pro 5Ghz Wifi problem

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

Yesterday, suddenly my Macbook's WiFi stopped working at school.

I have reason to think that only the 5GHz band is effected. Personal Hotspot connection via my iPhone still works and my Wifi at home also works.

There are a number of networks (e.g. eduroam) at my school but none of them work. My macbook connects to the 5GHz signals there and shows full signal strength. There are 2.4GHz BSSIDs but they share the same SSID and I could not figure out how to force the macbook to connect to the 2.4GHz ...

I run OSX 10.9.5 .

Pings to www.google.com or 8.8.8.8 timeout. Actually I can't even ping the Wifi routers The only traffic I see on the network (using little snitch) is MDNSresponder traffic ...

This is the log for turning on wifi and connecting to a signal:

```
25/11/14 08:05:01,000 kernel[0]: en1: setting diversity to: -1
25/11/14 08:05:01,000 kernel[0]: en1: Error configuring antenna diversity (index = -1).
25/11/14 08:05:01,000 kernel[0]: en1: setting tx antenna: -1
25/11/14 08:05:01,000 kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
25/11/14 08:05:02,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScanMultiple: Scan request received from 'airportd' (pid 91) (16 SSIDs, 0 BSSIDs).
25/11/14 08:05:02,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScanMultiple: Initiating scan.
25/11/14 08:05:03,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::scanDone: Scheduling cache purge timer in 30 seconds.
25/11/14 08:05:03,000 kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'US'.
25/11/14 08:05:03,000 kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
25/11/14 08:05:03,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for 'airportd' (pid 91).
25/11/14 08:05:03,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Broadcast scan request received from 'locationd' (pid 72) ().
25/11/14 08:05:03,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for 'locationd' (pid 72).
25/11/14 08:05:03,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScanMultiple: Scan request received from 'airportd' (pid 91) (16 SSIDs, 0 BSSIDs).
25/11/14 08:05:03,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScanMultiple: Initiating scan.
25/11/14 08:05:04,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for 'airportd' (pid 91).
25/11/14 08:05:04,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Broadcast scan request received from 'locationd' (pid 72) ().
25/11/14 08:05:04,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for 'locationd' (pid 72).
25/11/14 08:05:04,000 kernel[0]: en1: Terminating supplicant.
25/11/14 08:05:04,000 kernel[0]: RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for dc:a5:f4:9d:74:b1
25/11/14 08:05:04,813 eapolclient[4469]: en1 STOP
25/11/14 08:05:05,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c4:14:3c:cb:b4:d2  MAC AUTH succeeded
25/11/14 08:05:05,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
25/11/14 08:05:05,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en1
25/11/14 08:05:05,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to c4:14:3c:cb:b4:d2
25/11/14 08:05:06,000 kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
25/11/14 08:05:06,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Broadcast scan request received from 'airportd' (pid 91) ().
25/11/14 08:05:06,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for 'airportd' (pid 91).
25/11/14 08:05:06,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Broadcast scan request received from 'airportd' (pid 91) ().
25/11/14 08:05:06,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for 'airportd' (pid 91).
25/11/14 08:05:06,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Broadcast scan request received from 'SystemUIServer' (pid 295) ().
25/11/14 08:05:06,000 kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for 'SystemUIServer' (pid 295).
25/11/14 08:05:09,839 configd[18]: network changed: DNS* Proxy
25/11/14 08:05:09,855 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1655] en1: SSID 'UCSD-GUEST' making interface primary (cache indicates network not captive)
25/11/14 08:05:09,860 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Evaluating
25/11/14 08:05:09,869 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: en1: Not probing 'UCSD-GUEST' (cache indicates not captive)
25/11/14 08:05:09,869 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Authenticated
25/11/14 08:05:09,887 configd[18]: network changed: v4(en1!:172.17.4.54) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB+
25/11/14 08:05:15,211 AirPlayUIAgent[4475]: 2014-11-25 08:05:15.211446 AM [AirPlayUIAgent] Changed PIN pairing: no
25/11/14 08:05:15,273 AirPlayUIAgent[4475]: 2014-11-25 08:05:15.272642 AM [AirPlayUIAgent] Changed PIN pairing: no
25/11/14 08:05:15,434 Terminal[288]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2ac00001
25/11/14 08:05:15,435 Terminal[288]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x31000001
```

Does anyone have an idea what more I could try?

Here is a glympse into the DNS traffic in case that could be helpful:

[image: MDNSresponder capture]

Comment: Have you checked the DNS settings to make sure they are all right? Checked with your schools IT dept?

Comment: I will check with the IT dept but I suspect that they won't be very helpful. I don't think it's DNS because pinging IP addresses also does not work.

Comment: What was your solution?  I've a similar intermittent problem.

Comment: I was blocked by the university administration. -.-